# What is a default SSL Context and how many SSL Contexts can be configured?

Tags: java, ssl

In java we have javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault() which is described as: Returns the default SSL context.

This makes me think on the following questions:

1. When is the Default SSL Context created? Does this happen only while calling setDefault(SSLContext context)? What about the case where we pass -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mykeystore.jks? Is the default ssl context created based on this keystore? Also what happens in the case of a server environment like Tomcat? Does Tomcat set the default ssl context based on what is configured in keystoreFile="/keystore/tomcatkeystore.jks?
2. When we try to consume any https endpoint is the Default Context the one that is used?
3. When dealing with secure connections that require different set of keystores/configuration can we create new SSL Contexts without affecting what is already configured for the default ssl Context?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When is the Default SSL Context created? Does this happen only while calling setDefault(SSLContext context)?

No. If you use `setDefault` (which IME is pretty rare) you need to distinguish two 'levels' of default:

- the object returned by `.getDefault` -- this could be called the 'current default'. It *can* be set by `.setDefault` in which case you control the object set and its creation, or it *can* be created automatically, see next.
- the object created automatically and internally when `.getDefault` is called WITHOUT previously setting a value. This could be called the 'created default', or maybe the 'default default' (!) Once created this object is set as the default, so a *second* call to `.getDefault` goes back under the first bullet.

Most programs don't use `.setDefault` so if they use `.getDefault` at all (which they might not) then the first call goes to the second bullet and subsequent calls to the first.

Note `.getDefault` is called implicitly by many libraries, platforms, and middleware, so you can't assume that just because you don't write such a call it doesn't happen (and maybe invoke the second bullet).

> What about the case where we pass -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mykeystore.jks? Is the default ssl context created based on this keystore?

In the second bullet -- when you *don't* set a default and the default is automatically created, yes. More exactly, that 'created default' uses sysprops javax.net.ssl.keyStore* and ...trustStore* if set; if not it defaults the truststore to the file JRE/lib/security/cacerts (or jssecacerts if it exists, which is rare) and the keystore to none/empty.

If you set the default explicitly, you control what goes in it; you *may* use those sysprops if you choose to.

> Does Tomcat set the default ssl context based on what is configured in keystoreFile="/keystore/tomcatkeystore.jks?

No. It sets *a* context (there may be more than one) used to handle incoming HTTPS connections, but that is (or those are) not the *default* context.

> When we try to consume any https endpoint is the Default Context the one that is used?

Maybe. There are thousands of ways to 'consume ... https' and they can all be different. Some of them may always use the default context; many will sometimes use the default and sometimes not; some might never use the default. Without a much more specific question it is impossible to say.

> When dealing with secure connections that require different set of keystores/configuration can we create new SSL Contexts without affecting what is already configured for the default ssl Context?

Absolutely, and that is exactly what you should do. Note that some connection methods use the `SSLContext` directly, while some (mostly to be more compatible with non-SSL/TLS connections) use an `[SSL]SocketFactory` or `[SSL]ServerSocketFactory` created from and linked to the `SSLContext`. These accomplish the same result, but your code is slightly different.